# why does _vsnprintf cause an error

Tags: c++

I have a help function like this:

```
wchar* CHelpTool::PrintfToWstrFromStr( const char *content, ... )
{
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, content);
    int nLenstr = strlen(content);
    char*  pstrNum = (char*)MALLOC(nLenstr+50);
    LOG("PrintfToWstrFromStr11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
    LOG("PrintfToWstrFromStr    pstrNum ====================================%s", pstrNum);
    LOG("PrintfToWstrFromStr    nLenstr ====================================%d", nLenstr);
    LOG("PrintfToWstrFromStr    content ====================================%s", content);
    _vsnprintf(pstrNum, nLenstr+50-1, content, argp);
    LOG("PrintfToWstrFromStr2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222");
    AECHAR* wpstrNum = CHelpTool::StrToWstr(pstrNum);
    FREEIF(pstrNum);
    va_end(argp);

    return wpstrNum;
}
```

When it comes to `_vsnprintf`, the program collapses.
and the log is:

```
pstrNum ====================================  
nLenstr ====================================68  
content ====================================Gi?m phòng ??ch, t?ng %d%% sát th??ng, kéo dài 2 l??t
```

It goes well by note the `function _vsnprintf`.

What's the problem with my function?

Comment: what is happening in your debugger?

Comment: Well, see for yourself what `pstrNum` is.

Comment: When `LOG`ging `pstrNum`, you're dumping uninitialized data. What did you expect to happen? And since you're somehow trying to convert an MBCS string to a Unicode string, the `LOG` of `content` may be correct. Just not the right encoding. **Hint:** Why not use the `LOG` implementation as an inspiration? Unless that was also written by yourself, chances are that it isn't nearly as wrong as your code.

Comment: seems the error is within the content string... it's length is 68 but it has some non-ascii characters.

Comment: wow ... that is one broken function.  Is it crashing inside of `_vsnprintf`?

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` is returning the wrong value, `content` is clearly longer than 18 characters (68-50). It looks like you have a multi-byte string being passed in, you may want to have

```
int nLenstr = mblen(content, MB_CUR_MAX);
```

This will get you the correct string length.

As far as the crash goes. I'm going to guess `_vsnprintf()` can't handle having the buffer end while in the middle of a multi-byte sequence.